# android--1 missing in qt

Tags: android, qt

I am an absolute beginner. I am trying to build a qt android project but I keep getting an error. The error is :

> Warning: Android platform 'android--1' does not exist in SDK. File
>   /home/tintin/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.

  > Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.926 secs
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
13:37:37: The process /home/tintin/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project tintin (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.1 for Android armv7))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
13:37:37: Elapsed time: 00:13.
```

How do I correct this?